# Connecting to a Kubernetes service resulted in connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks, kubernetes-service

I'm trying to deploy my web application using Kubernetes. I used Minikube to create the cluster and successfully exposed my frontend react app using ingress. Yet when I attached the backend service's URL in "env" field in the frontend's deployment.yaml, it does not work. When I tried to connect to the backend service through the frontend pod, the connection refused.

frontend deployment yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
 name: frontend
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: frontend
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: frontend
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: frontend
         image: <image_name>
         imagePullPolicy: Never
         ports:
           - containerPort: 80
         env:
         - name: REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT
           value: http://backend-svc
     restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: frontend-svc
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
 selector:
   app: frontend
```

Ingress for frontend

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: front-ingress
 namespace: default
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
 rules:
   - host: front-testk.info
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: frontend-svc
               port:
                 number: 80
```

Backend deployment yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: <image_name>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: Always
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-svc
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

```
% kubectl get svc backend-svc -o wide
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
backend-svc   ClusterIP   10.109.107.145   <none>        80/TCP    21h   app=backend
```

Connected inside frontend pod and try to connect to the backend using the ENV created during deploy:

```
❯ kubectl exec frontend-75579c8499-x766s -it sh
/app # apk update && apk add curl
OK: 10 MiB in 20 packages

/app # env
REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT=http://backend-svc

/app # curl $REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT
curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend-svc port 80: Connection refused

/app # nslookup backend-svc
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   backend-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.109.107.145

** server can't find backend-svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Exec into my backend pod

```
# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/node

# netstat -lnturp
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get svc backend-svc -o wide` too here?

Comment: @vishal Thanks for the suggestion, I just added that.

Comment: check the status of your control plane pods, core-dns pods. See if there is anything helpful in the control plane pod logs. check if there is any network-policy in place that denies communication between pods.

Comment: what is your namespace for backend  ? dns should be backend-svc.default.cluster.local if namespace is default ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan According to the yamls he has posted, he didn't mention any namespace in the metadata which means it will be deployed in the default ns automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification vishal. @ThanhNguyenVan all the resources are deployed in the default namespace

Comment: Connection refused suggest two possible things: 1. Your backend app does not listen on port you specified. 2. You app is binding to localhost.  Can you please exec into your backend pod and check if/which ports are opened with `netstat -lnturp`.

Comment: @thomas thanks for the advice, I just edited the post. I am still new to networking, please let me know if you found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected your application listens on port 8080. If you closely at your output from `netstat` you will notice that `Local Address` is `0.0.0.0:8080`:

```
# netstat -tulpn

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/node
```

In order to fix that you have to correct your `targetPort` in your service:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-svc
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080 #  change this to 8080
```

There is no need to change the port on the deployment side since the `containerPort` is primarily informational. Not specifying a port there does not prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is listening on the default `"0.0.0.0"` address inside a container will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the remainder. The modified deployment yaml still result in connection refused.

Comment: That is really strange. I`ve checked your yaml files with different images and the frontend app was able to connect the backed. So the fault is definitely at your backed app side. Just to confirm, you modified deployment or service?

Comment: I've modified the targetPort of the service as you suggested. Thanks for verifying, I will try to use another image for the backend and see if it works

Comment: I was using [mendhak/http-https-echo](https://hub.docker.com/r/mendhak/http-https-echo). It`s very good for testing things out.

Comment: I have deployed a test pod with the same configuration suggested here [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/), and it has no problem running `nslookup backend-svc.default` and `nslookup kubernetes.default`. My frontend pod is using a Alpine image, do you think that is the problem as suggested here [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30215)

Comment: Well it appears that this might be the cause of this since there were issues with dns in alpine images. Having this image at the beginning would definitely speed up the process. I was testing this with centos container on front end. You will have to use different image for frontend application.

Comment: @yhshj would you please consider [upvoting/accetping](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer?